# converting facebook javascript sdk variables into asp variables?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have a facebook sign up and login button build using js sdk. I want to store user response into a database, but I cant get the userID or User.email with classic asp. 
Sometimes it works, sometimes not, can't find pattern.

```
    var email=response.email;
    var fbid=response.id;
    var fbname=response.name;
    var fbbirthday=response.birthday;
    var fbhometown=response.hometown.name;

    document.getElementById('fbmail').value = email;
    document.getElementById('fbid').value = fbid;
     document.getElementById('fbname').value = fbname;
      document.getElementById('fbbirthday').value = fbbirthday;
       document.getElementById('fbhometown').value = fbhometown;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use classic ASP to get all of that information server-side.  You would need to build your own framework to wrap up the HTTP Get/Post/Delete commands to the Graph API.  But to accomplish getting that basic user information should be fairly straight forward once you have nice wrappers around those three HTTP verbs.

A quickie solution would be to FORM post those values back to the server.  I assume you have https, so security shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What kind of security problems I will encounter if I use http?

Comment: Use HTTPS then.  Whatever you want to use, it's up to you.